# asp.net access config file in a test environment

Tags: asp.net

I'm writing unit tests for an asp.net mvc project.  I have a config file that I use in my tests, but for some reason, the config file has to be in in the bin folder in order to be found.  Is there another way to do this as I don't feel it is best practice in having config files in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

During compilation, your app.config file is copied automatically from the root directory to the bin folder. You shouldn't have to manually place an app.config file in the bin folder.

Assuming your project name is

> MyTestProject

then after a build your bin should contain the following:

```
MyTestProject.dll
MyTestProject.dll.config
```

Plus any other referenced assemblies.

One interesting thing about this is that if, in Solution Explorer, you right click your app.config and go to properties (F4) you should see that the "Copy to Output Directory" option is set to "Do not copy". This is correct. The compiler should handle the copying and renaming. If you had the setting set to "Copy always", your bin would contain a file called `app.config`, which the runtime would ignore.

**EDIT:** If you are referencing other config files from within your app.config (or web.config for that matter) then these files will need to be deployed to the appropriate directory. An example of this might be a `Spring.config` file, referenced in the app.config:

```
<spring>
    <context type="Spring.Context.Support.WebApplicationContext, Spring.Web">
        <resource uri="~/Spring.config"/>
    </context>
</spring>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, does this work for other custom config files or is this limited to app.config?

Comment: I am assuming that your unit tests are in a separate assembly to your website as per the default asp.net mvc solution template? I hope so. With ASP.NET, the web.config is copied as part of the deployment to the application or virtual folder directory. Could you please explain which other config files you mean?

Comment: Hi Daniel I am using castle windsor for dependency injection, it has its own config file which is used to associate types to interface services, in my test environment I want to have a different copy of this config file

Comment: Ah, do you mean that you want to have a different version of the config in each environment?